# I source a file each day - is it dangerous by means of filling up the disk drive?

Tags: source

I `source` a file each day - is it dangerous by means of filling up the disk drive (if something is written anywhere)?

Someone once criticized me here in StackExchange for sourcing a file each minute (something I no longer do), I think it was something like "you are creating the file each minute!"

I'm not sure exactly, but even if I do it daily, is there any danger in this, by means of disk space? If so, what approach you'll take to protect the environment from such damage?

Comment: Please [edit] your question, and specify which command are you running

Comment: What? Sourcing a file won’t write anything to disk in and of itself.

Comment: ... in which case, sourcing the *same* file each minute or each day is useless (and possibly harmful). You only want to source a file when it changes (or when you first log in to the system). You also have to be careful to e.g. avoid extending a variable's value every time you source it (think `PATH=/foo/bar:$PATH`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, sourcing a file or running a script daily, hourly or even every minute, is in itself not "dangerous", but it depends on what the script is doing.

For example, a script that creates temporary files, fills them with data and does not clean up after itself will, eventually, fill up a partition.

A file that modifies environment variables may blindly add values to e.g. `PATH` without testing whether those values are not already part of `$PATH`. Eventually, such a script would make it difficult to execute utilities on the command line if it was sourced many *many* times (the length of the command line plus the length of all environment variables and their values is limited to a particular value).

Some disk media is susceptible to wear, and some users go to great lengths to *not* write things to the physical disk (mounting filesystems in RAM, turning off write access on as many other mount points as possible etc). On such systems, the act of creating a file every minute may be considered less good (possibly depending on the size of the file)

The take-home message here is this: Sourcing or running a script often is not bad practice, *depending on what it does*. Making sure that scripts that you write does proper cleaning up and are able to detect when it's appropriate to make certain modifications is also good practice.